# Pytest Error - Comparing object location to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Im trying to test an object that i have made in python from data i am pulling from a file but i keep getting the error `self.assertEquals(Create("input.txt"), "1/2") AssertionError: <dsadsa.Create object at 0x0340EAD0> != '1/2'`

How would i get actual data instead of the object instead of the place where it is stored in Pytest?

Here is my code where i am pulling data and creating an object:

```
class Run:
    def __init__(self, first, second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.first}/{self.second}"

class Create:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file_contents = [line.rstrip("\n)") for line in open(file)]
        self.all = []
        self.add()
        self.prnt()

    def add(self):
        for i in self.file_contents:
            first, second = i.split(",")
            self.all.append(Run(first,second))

    def prnt(self):
        for i in self.all:
            print(i)

def main():
    Create("input.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And here is my Pytest script to test the object:

```
import unittest
from dsadsa import Create

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one(self):
        self.assertEquals(Create("input.txt"), "1/2")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here is my file data:
    `1,2`

any help/suggestions on this would be appreciated.

SOLUTION -

```
a = Create("input.txt") # Make an istance and then use the self.all attribute to get data to compare
self.assertEqual(str(a.all[0]), "1/2")
```

Comment: its probably located in the `Create.all` attribute

Comment: @aws_apprentice that works! perfect. thank you.

Comment: np, did you write these classes? if yes then you should probably know how they work

Comment: @aws_apprentice i do know how they work, just thought if there was an easier way to change the data location to the actual values to compare